# Spring @Valid works for form requests but not with JSON body

Tags: json, spring, validation, spring-mvc, spring-validator

I have a simple data transfer class

```
@Data
public class UserDto {

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String email;
}
```

In my controller I want to use the object.

```
@PostMapping("/users/create")
public ResponseEntity<Object> createUser(@ModelAttribute("UserDto") @RequestBody @Valid UserDto accountDto, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest request)  {
    System.out.println(accountDto);
    System.out.println(accountDto.getUsername());
    System.out.println(accountDto.getPassword());
    System.out.println(bindingResult.hasErrors());

    return new ResponseEntity<>("success", HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

I am using postman to test my api. The requests work fine when sending it as a `form` or `x-www-form-urlencoded`. I get following output:

> UserDto(username=dsfssf, password=dsfsdgfsg, email=ssfds@dsgfsg.com)
>
> dsfssf
>
> dsfsdgfsg
>
> false

However, when sending the request as a JSON object like

```
{"username": "ssss", "password": "test", "email": "samauaa@sdfsdfsd.com" }
```

All I am getting is

> UserDto(username=null, password=null, email=null)
>
> null
>
> null
>
> true

Comment: Have you tried removing the @ModelAttribute and test it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `@ModelAttribute` or it will look for the data inside the request parameters.

`@RequestBody` alone tells Spring to look for the data inside the request body.